# Align text vertically in

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to align some text vertically in **bootstrap** *div*.I want text with *fixed height* and *fixed padding*, but it doesn't work.And also is it possible to stretch text to the *fixed height* and dynamically assign *font size*?
[link](https://jsfiddle.net/elene/640kLut2/)

```
    <div class="section ">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-hidden col-xs-hidden" style="height:800px;
      ">
            <div id="studio"> studio abc</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

#studio {
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  font-size: 180px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-top: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="section ">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-hidden col-xs-hidden">
        <div id="studio">
          <div>
            studio<br/>abc
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.section {
  background-color: blue;
}

#studio {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height:800px;
}

#studio > div {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  font-size: 180px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```